# Isolated points both exist on interior and boundary

Tags: general-topology

X: topl space,

A: subset of X

In standard topology, isolated points of A looks like exist only on boundary.

In discrete topology, isolated points of A looks like exist only on interior since there is no boundary in discrete topology.

Is there any example of isolated points both exist on interior and boundary?

Comment: What is the "Standard" topology on your space?

Comment: @KyleGannon For example, you might think X=R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Take the disjoint union of $X$ bearing the discrete topology and $X$ with the "standard"  topology (whataver that may mean). Then a set with points in both copies of $X$ may have isolated points in both its interior and its boundary.

Comment: Hard. Could you please tell me with concrete example? You might take X=R...

Comment: Let $X=R$. Let $\tau$ be the standard topology, and $\sigma$ be the discrete topology. Let your space be $(X,\tau)\sqcup (X,\sigma)$. Let $A_1=\{1,2,3\}\subset (X,\tau)$ and $A_2=\{1,2,3\}\subset (X,\sigma)$. Then let $A=A_1\cup A_2$, and so that every point is an isolated point. The points in $A_1$ are boundary points, and the points in $A_2$ are interior points.